# How to send a mail using xsmtplib in place of smtplib. As xsmtplib do not ask for login password unlike smtplib

Tags: python, email, send, pypi, smtplib

As per pipy.org

Way to use xsmtplib is as follows:

```
  from xsmtplib import SMTP<br/>
  server = SMTP(host="smtp.example.com", proxy_host="proxy.example.com")<br/>
  server.sendmail("user@example.com", "admin@example.com", "I have an issue. Please help!")<br/>
  server.quit()
```

But I want to first login with password and then send.
Similar to :

```
    server = xsmtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)<br/>
    server.ehlo()<br/>
    server.starttls()<br/>
    server.ehlo()<br/>
    server.login("xxxx@gmail.com", "zzzzz")<br/>
    message = f"Dear Sir,\n\nThere is a price drop for your selected product. Current Price is {price}.\n Regards"<br/>
    server.sendmail("xxxx@gmail.com", "yyyy@gmail.com", message)<br/>
```

Comment: Presumably you do `server.login` without `server.starttls`, as the project readme says SSL isn't supported yet?  While being aware that this will expose your password on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to use     "xsmtplib.xsmtplib.SMTP" rest is all similar to smtplib.

```
server = xsmtplib.xsmtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("xxxx@gmail.com", "zzzzz")<br/>
message = f"Dear Sir,\n\nThere is a price drop for your selected product. Current Price is {price}.\n Regards"
server.sendmail("xxxx@gmail.com", "yyyy@gmail.com", message)
```